# Ashcroft Mermin Solid State Eq. 22.15

Tags: material-science, crystals

I recently read a paper on [Specific heat of a Classical Crystal: Dulong-Petit law](http://www.uvm.edu/~dcloughe/ph341/A+M-Chapter%2022.pdf).

In Eq. `22.15`, I don't understand why the ionic displacement $\mathbf{u}$ and momentum $\mathbf{P}$ become independent of temperature after $\beta^\frac{-1}{2}$ is extracted. Where does this $\beta^\frac{-1}{2}$ come from?

Comment: Comment to the question (v4): It would be good if OP (or somebody else?) could try to make the question formulation self-contained, so one doesn't have to open the link to understand the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a mathematical trick to factor $\beta$ out of an integral.  $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{P}$ don't depend on temperature, but $\mathbf{\bar{u}}$ and $\mathbf{\bar{P}}$ do.  But the barred versions appear only as dummy variables in an integral, so their dependence on $\beta$ is immaterial.  This simplifies what comes next.  I don't see any way of making intuitive sense out of it.

Comment: Thank you, but could you say more about the "dummy variables" in the integral? Why does the integral in braces become independent of temperature?

And how does $d\mathbf{u}=\beta^{-3/2}d\mathbf{\bar{u}}$ come from $\mathbf{u}$=$\beta^{-1/2}\mathbf{\bar{u}}$?

Comment: Thank you garyp! After I studied the equations and your comments further, I understand them now.